# sending JSON Object from python to javascript to populate dropdown list

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I want to add a dropdown list to my table (for each row in same column).I managed to do this but only if the arrays are written in the javascript.

What I want to do now, is to populate my dropdown list with the values from an Excel file. Since that is not so easy I created a python file where I convert this excel file as a JSON file and take only the sheet from where the values should be imported. But What I don't know is how to call my JSON object from python in the javascript

convert_excel_file.py :

```
import pandas as pd

path_to_excel = "//10.0.254.14/data/file_to_read_from.xlsm"
export_m42OUs = pd.read_excel(path_to_excel,sheet_name='m42OUs')
json_m42OUs = export_m42OUs.to_json(orient='records')
print(json_m42OUs)
```

which gives me JSON file that looks something like this :

```
[{"OU_ID":"OU00001","OU_IDName":"Global"},
{"OU_ID":"OU00086","OU_IDName":"DEMO_01"},
{"OU_ID":"OU00087","OU_IDName":"DEMO_02"},
...]
```

I have to note that I can't just write the values in JS because the Excel file can be updated and new values can be added which is not the best solution for me.

I tried few codes I found on stack but none of them worked :/

**EDIT** : I corrected the path now it doesn't show 404Error anymore but I still don't know how to get the data . I just tried this code :

```
 let dropdown = $('#OUsList');
    dropdown.empty();

    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabeld>Choose</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex',0);

    const url='http://107.0.0.1:5000/my_app/convert_excel_file.py';

    //Populate dropdown with the list
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key,entry){
            dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.OU_ID).text(entry.OU_IDName))
        });
    });
```

**EDIT 2:**
after 15 sec after runing the code it returned me this error:
`jquery-1.12.4.js:10254 GET http://107.0.0.1:5000/my_app/convert_excel_file.py net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: Not sure if will help but 404 error indicates that the resource, in your case convert_excel_file.py, is not found on the server, check the logs and the configuration of the 107.0.0.1 machine

Comment: It's not an AJAX problem. It can't find the url. Maybe the AJAX call should be a GET instead of a POST?

Comment: I corrected the path to my python file it doesn't show the 404 Error anymore but I am still no closer to figuring out how to get access to the values. I added another code I used to try

Comment: @AmilaBečirović have a look at the browser console and tell us if you see any errors there (ctrl+shift+j if you're on chrome)

Comment: this ist what I get when I run the code I added in my Edit  `jquery-1.12.4.js:10254 GET http://107.0.0.1:5000/my_app/convert_excel_file.py net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Answer (score 0):

You need create to a simple web app to serve your JSON, Your javascript looks OK but your server side python is not ran the way you intend to.

I'd recommend you use some lightweight framework like [CherryPy](https://cherrypy.org/) to return a JSON HTPP response.